# iOS app to make a call from app with TWILIO

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip

I need to create an app for iOS that lets the user to call any number via VoIP.
I'm trying to implement the quickstart guide for twilio that I found here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios/get-started#bullet9

The app starts well but when I insert a number and press on "Call", a voice says me that an error occurred.
In the twilio console I found this error:

> An attempt to retrieve content from
> https://my-quickstart-dev.twil.io/make-call returned the HTTP status
> code 404

But I cannot understand what it means... that URL is from the tutorial... with which URL I should substitute it?
In addition, following the tutorial, I wrote my verified number in the field "callerNumber" of the fields of the server make-call.js and place-call.js

I'm very new with the VoIP services so I'm trying to understand how to implement ad app-to-phone service (tried twilio and vonage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to read [TWILIO quick-start](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios) tutorial carefully.
In the second step, you have to create your server, following [this tutorial](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python) from TWILIO and create a python server.

Then, replace your https://my-quickstart-dev.twil.io/make-call to your url https://your-url.ngrok.io/makecall

Comment: Hi! Ok thanks for the response... i thought that for using twilio i would't need a server (it  is possbile)?

In any case, following the tutorial, after twilio login command, it returns me an api key without a secret code becouse the api that the command create is a stantard type...